# google sheets gives the option of using apikey for javascript but does not work

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, google-sheets-api

i am trying to send four points of data to a spread sheet from a website i am developing. name, email, subject, message.

```
function loadClient() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(myapikey);
      return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/sheets/v4/rest")
          .then(function() {
            console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");
          }, function(error) {
            console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API");
          });
    }
    // Make sure the client is loaded before calling this method.
    function execute() {
      return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
        "spreadsheetId": mysheetid,
        "range": "a1",
        "includeValuesInResponse": "false",
        "insertDataOption": "INSERT_ROWS",
        "responseDateTimeRenderOption": "SERIAL_NUMBER",
        "responseValueRenderOption": "FORMATTED_VALUE",
        "valueInputOption": "RAW",
        "resource": {
          "values": [
            [
              "test@text.com",
              "jimmy clarke",
              "subject",
              "this is a test email"
            ]
          ]
        }
      })
          .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          }, function(error) {
            console.error("Execute error", error);
          });
    }
    gapi.load("client");
  </script>
```

i expected it to send the data to the google sheet without error.

it tells me that this can only be sent using oauth.

i would prefer not to use oauth. my main pain point is that when i look at the (google made) templates it allows for the use of the api key, though when i run the code i recieve and i receive this error

> Object { 
>           result: {…}, 
>           body: "{\n  \"error\": 
>               {\n    \"code\": 401,\n    \"message\": \"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.\",\n    \"status\": "UNAUTHENTICATED\"\n  }\n}\n", headers: {…}, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized" }

Could i have made a mistake in setting it up?

Answer (score 0):

May have found the answer i believe it is due to the fact that i left the 
spread sheet as private, which would require the use of the oauth.